# Using hidden input to send extra data with Ajax

Tags: html, ajax, forms, hidden-field

Currently I'm using hidden inputs to send some extra values with Ajax when a user submits a form. The reason I'm using hidden values is because I can have a long list with textfields an assigned button to each textfield. With every button click I have to send the value in the textfield plus some extra values.

The problem is that anyone can inspect the code in Chrome (for example) and change the values in the hidden field. Is there any better way of doing this?

---

EDIT: Added some code to better illustrate my problem

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="textfield" name="value1" value="Default value for textfield" />
    <input type="hidden" class="hiddenValue" name="hiddenSuperSecretValue" value="superSecret" />
    <button class="submitButton">Submit</button>

    <input type="textfield" name="value2" value="Default value for textfield" />
    <input type="hidden" class="hiddenValue" name="hiddenSuperSecretValue" value="superSecret" />
    <button class="submitButton">Submit</button>
    ... more fields ...
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.submitButton').click(function(){
    dataVar = "someValue" = $(this).closest('.hiddenValue').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/submitAjaxStuff.php",
        data: dataVar,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            doSomething(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a server side language like PHP then a better option would be to store the hidden values in the session so the user has no access to them.

Comment: Since I have different values for each field and I don't want to use a ajax function for each and every field I don't know how to use session for that. See my edit of the original post.